# How to get Particular Users First Message using gmail api

Tags: python, python-3.x, gmail-api

how to get the first message of a particular user(like facebook's first message to me) using using gmail api

currently i'm using this code to get all the messages

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly'

def main():

    store = file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('gmail', 'v1', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

# Call the Gmail API to fetch INBOX
results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me',maxResults=20,labelIds = ['INBOX']).execute()
messages = results.get('messages', [])

if not messages:
    print("No messages found.")
else:
    print("Message snippets:")
    for message in messages:
        msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id']).execute()
        print(msg['snippet'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: what about `first_msg = messages[:1]`?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your code, I think you need to replace below code snippet

```
for message in messages:
        msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id']).execute()
        print(msg['snippet'])
```

with following code snippet,

```
msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=messages[-1]['id']).execute()
print(msg['snippet'])
```

Comment: it will give you the latest one right ?  How to get the first message of a particular user suppose a sender(xxxxx@gmail.com) has sent me 100 emails i want only the first

Comment: Did you solve it? 0 can be replaced by -1
updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Get the length of messages :

```
last_index = len(messages) - 1

msg = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=messages[last_index]['id']).execute()
print(msg['snippet'])
```

Comment: The last element in the list can be accessed by `-1` or `(last_index-1)`